# how to write this query in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two tables

```
1. menu

id      -     menu_name    -     menu_url
1       -     Home         -      index
2       -     About        -      about
3       -     Services     -            
4       -     Contact      -      contact

2. submenu 

id      -     menu_name    -     submenu_name  
1       -     Services     -      Web Development
2       -     Services     -      Web Designing
3       -     Services     -      Logo Designing      
4       -     Services     -      SEO
```

for that i have created this query in php

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menu");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
      if ($row['menu_url'] == ''){
        $subquery = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM submenu WHERE 
        menu_name = '".$row['menu_name']."'");
          while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subquery)){
            //do something here
           }
        }else{
           //do something here
        }
}
```

my question is that how do i do this query in laravel ?

my controller query

```
$menu = menu::all();

$submenu = submenu::where('menu_name','i want the $menu->menu_name variable here')->get();
```

how to get that variable in second query.

Thanks in advance any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `$submenu=submenu::where('menu_name', $yourVariable)->get();` I dont really understand what you try to achieve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better if you create one-to-many relationship between `Menu` and `Submenu` models, in order to do this it would be better if you provide Foreign Key `menu_id` in `sumbenu` table;

So you will have two tables with following columns:

```
menu{id(primary_key), menu_name, menu_url(better to provide slug not url)};
sumenu{id(primary_key), menu_id(foreign_key pointing to menu tables id), sumbenu_name, submenu_url(better to provide slug not url)}
```

After you can define relationships in each model

Menu Model:

```
public function submenus()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\SubMenu');
    }
```

SubMenu Model:

```
public function menu()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Menu');
    }
```

after all you can do `$menuitems = Menu::all()` , then pass the $menus variable to frontend view, and in frontend you can write

```
@foreach($menuitems as $menuitem)
{{ menuitem }}
    @foreach($menuitem->submenus as $submenu )
       {{ submenu }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

That's it :)

Comment: thanks for answering but i got error "Use of undefined constant submenus - assumed 'submenus' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)"

Comment: Where did you get this error ? :) you need to add '->' instead of '.'

Comment: on my view Use of undefined constant submenus - assumed 'submenus' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View: D:\livian-data\recruitworld-laravel\resources\views\layout\app.blade.php) (View: D:\livian-data\recruitworld-laravel\resources\views\layout\app.blade.php)

Comment: That's because I think you have $menuitem.submenus instead of $menuitem->submenus, I edited the code an updated use $menuitem->submenus instead

Comment: yes you r right but again now i got this error      Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: D:\livian-data\recruitworld-laravel\resources\views\layout\app.blade.php) (View: D:\livian-data\recruitworld-laravel\resources\views\layout\app.blade.php)       on same line

Comment: Have you defined relationship? and what data do you have on DB? also you can check it using "php artisan tinker" using command line go to your laravels folder and type php artisan tinker, then namespace app, and then type Menuitem::first(), what you get?? then type Menuitem::first()->submenus, if you have items added they will be listed there

Comment: But what if i have where clause in both queries i.e where active='1' in menu table and active='1' in submenu table how do i apply this where clause ?

Comment: Menu::where('active', 1)->get()

Comment: it will apply to both the tables ??

Comment: It will apply to model if you want to filter collection look here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-filter

Comment: You should accept this answer if it worked for you @livianshrawnia

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient way:

```
$all_sub_menu = Submenu::get();

$all_sub_menu = collect($all_sub_menu)->groupBy('menu_name');

foreach( $menu as $m )  // To get the individual records
{

    if(isset($all_sub_menu[$m->menu_name]){
        $sub_menu = $all_sub_menu[$m->menu_name]; 
        // you will get submenu for the current menu without requesting the database again and again
    }
    else{
        $sub_menu = array();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$menu=menu::all();

if( count( $menu ) > 0 )  // Iterate only when there is some data available
{
    foreach( $menu as $m )  // To get the individual records
    {
        $submenu=submenu::where('menu_name', $m->menu_name)->get();

        // here $submenu is an Std Class object, so use foreach() in the same way as above
    }
}
```

**P.S.:** Querying inside a loop is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try below codes :

number 1 :

```
$menu=menu::all();

$menu->each(
    function($eachMenu)
    {
        $submenu[] = submenu::where('menu_name', $eachMenu->menu_name)->get();
    }
)
```

number 2:

```
$menu=menu::all();

foreach($menu as $eachMenu) {
    $submenu[] = submenu::where('menu_name', $eachMenu->menu_name)->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first query (and loop) are unnecessary:

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM submenu x
  JOIN menu y
    ON y.menu_name = x.menu_name;
```

I'll leave the laravel bit as an exercise for the reader

Also, as mentioned by others, you should use the PK of the menu table as the FK of the submenu table.